Please help me in giving me the idea of making the following diagram

My approach is in this way.
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{row sep/normal=50pt, column sep/normal=50pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r, "\phi"]  \arrow[d, red]\arrow[dr]
    & B \arrow[d, "\psi"]  \arrow[l] \arrow[dl,crossing over]\\
    C \arrow[r, "\eta"] \arrow[u]
    & \arrow[l]  \arrow[u]D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}

I am facing a problem because I cannot make the two arrows simultaneously. See the output 

What do you mean, simultaneously? Look at the keys shift right and shift left from tikz-cd.

To extend my comment:
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{row sep/normal=50pt, column sep/normal=50pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow[r, "\phi"', shift right]  \arrow[d, red, shift right]\arrow[dr]
        & B \arrow[d, "\psi"', shift right]  \arrow[l, shift right] \arrow[dl,crossing over]\\
        C \arrow[r, "\eta"', shift right] \arrow[u, shift right]
        & \arrow[l, shift right]  \arrow[u, shift right]D
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}


